# boost::get boost::variant no giving the correct output

Tags: c++, boost-variant

I have the following function

```
template <typename T, typename U>
const T* visitor_fct(U& operand)
{
  return (boost::get<T>(&operand));
}
```

When I do

```
 boost::variant<int, std::string> str = "string";
 std::cout << visitor_fct<std::string>(str) << std::endl;
```

I get the correct output

But when I change the declaration of str to :

`boost::variant<int, std::string, bool> str = "toto";`

I am always getting a `nullptr`;

Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that a string literal (`char*`)converts to `bool` better than to `std::string` so your string literal doesn't initialize the `string` component of the variant, but rather than `bool` component (to true).

See the following which outputs `bool 1`:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(bool b)
{
    std::cout << "bool " << b << std::endl;
}

void foo(std::string s)
{
    std::cout << "string " << s << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo("Bar");
}
```

Initializing with `std::string("toto")` will solve your problem.

4.12/1 shows us the conversion in question:

```
A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a
prvalue of type bool. A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to false;
any other value is converted to true. A prvalue of type std::nullptr_t can be converted to a prvalue of
type bool; the resulting value is false.
```

[As noted also in the other answer] This implicit conversion takes precedence over the converting constructor of `std::string` and so is selected, causing the type used in the variant to be `bool`.

Answer (score 2):

What seems to be happening here is because there's a bool present in the boost::variant, the const char* you're passing is no longer used for the string but rather is converted to bool.

if you change this line:

```
boost::variant<int, std::string, bool> str = "toto";
```

to this:

```
boost::variant<int, std::string, bool> str = std::string("toto");
```

it will work.

Here's why the bool gets chosen over the string: implicit conversions happen between any types of pointer and bool, and conversions between built-in types are always preferred to user-defined conversions. And since std::string is a user defined type (standard mind you but still user defined) the bool wins over the string.